Which program is used in this shot of the movie "The Wrong Woman"
There is a software screen shown at minute 4 in the  1995 movie The Wrong Woman. What Software was used?


Microsoft Excel for Macintosh:

(Image taken from the Excel Page of the quite useful Macintosh Repository)
... after all, it's a Macintosh computer. Most likely a Centris or Quadra 610. Both introduced in 1993, so good timing for a 1995 movie with an up to date setup.

And they conveniently hid the Apple logo...

Also look at the keyboard; third key from the bottom left. It's not particularly clear but that's an apple and roundabout from a mac keyboard.
